# Congruence of Squares for Factoring

Tags: factoring

After coming across the assertion that given

$$
    x^2 = y^2 \pmod n \\
    x \neq \pm y \pmod n
$$

we can then conclude that n factors into

$$
    n = \mathrm{gcd}(n, x-y) \mathrm{gcd}(n, x+y).
$$

in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_of_squares) article, I attempted my own example but it doesn't seem to work.  I think there's a missing hypothesis, but more importantly, I'm interested in understanding why this would work under the correct conditions.

---

First, the example given was

$$
\begin{align*}
    &6^2 = 1^2 \pmod {35} \\
    &x+y = 7 \\
    &x-y = 5
\end{align*}
$$

So applying the gcd with $35$ simply retains the values, yielding the correct factorization

$$35 = 7 \times 5.$$

---

However, my test example was

$$
\begin{align*}
    &8^2 = 4^2 \pmod {24} \\
    &x+y = 12 \\
    &x-y = 4
\end{align*}
$$
If we just blindly applied the stated result, we would get

$$24 = 12 \times 4.$$

I would guess the problem is that my selected factors are not coprime.  Does anyone have any intuition for why this method works (when it works) or any hints towards a proof?

---

After some brief pondering, I've noticed it certainly works if the values $x+y$ and $x-y$ are coprime.  Their product divides $n$ yet they contain no overlapping factors, so by collecting the factors of $x+y$ and $x-y$ which are also factors of $n$, we will end up with precisely all the factors of $n$ and nothing extra.

Comment: Where did you come across that  assertion?

Comment: In the linked wikipedia article a few lines into my post

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question on elementary number theory not having much to do with computer science per se.

Answer (score 1):

The  assertion is not correct in general, as you have discovered.

However, here is what *is* correct:  $\gcd(x+y,n)$ is a factor  of $n$, and $\gcd(x-y,n)$ is a factor  of $n$.  Why?  Well, this is trivial: $\gcd(\text{anything},n)$ is always a  factor of $n$.  Of course, the gcd might be 1, but that's still a divisor of $n$.

We can say even more.   If we let $r=\gcd(x+y,n)$ and $s=\gcd(x-y,n)$, then their product is a multiple of $n$: i.e., $rs$ is a multiple of $n$.  Thus, you can replace $s$ with $s'=n/r$ and now $r,s'$ will have the property you want: both $r$ and $s'$ are divisors of  $n$, and $rs'=n$.  (Why is $rs$ a multiple of $n$? Because if  $x^2  \equiv y^2 \pmod n$, then it follows that $x^2 - y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod n$.  Now $x^2-y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$, so it follows that $n$ divides $(x-y)(x+y)$, i.e., $n$ divides $rs$.)

This makes this method useful for factoring.  However, beware that there is no guarantee that get a non-trivial factor out of this.  For instance, consider $n=15$.   Then if $x=8$ and $y=7$, we have $x^2 \equiv y^2 \equiv 4 \pmod n$, but $\gcd(x-y,n)=1 $ and $\gcd(x+y,n)=15$, so we obtain that $15 = 1 \times 15$ -- true, but not very useful for factoring $n$.  What we can say is that if $n$  is the product of two large primes, and if you can randomly sample  two $x,y$ such that $x^2 \equiv y^2 \pmod n$, then with probability about $1/2$, $\gcd(x-y,n)$ and $\gcd(x+y,n)$ will give you the full factorization of $n$.

If you want us to comment on an assertion it helps to give a reference for it.  My guess would be that there is additional context you are not  providing, such as the assumption that $n$ is a product of two primes.

Comment: "My guess would be that there is additional context you are not providing, such as ..."  -> No, I linked the wikipedia article, so that's the full context...

Comment: @Apollys, The Wikipedia  article doesn't make the assertion that you said you came across.  The Wikipedia  article never says that $n$ factors into $\gcd(n,x-y) \times \gcd(n,x+y)$.   What it *does* say is that $n$ divides that product... not that $n$ is equal to that product.

Comment: why is the probability about 1/2?

Comment: @omg, The justification is longer than I can fit in a comment.  I suggest reading about Fermat's factoring method, and if you're still stuck, ask on Math.SE.